# Count occurencies of value from csv column in other file/s and append as a new column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

can I make this work with basic shell tools(no Python or Perl)?

INPUT1:

```
file1.csv
    John,Doe,john@mail.com
    Andy,Barry,barry@mail.com
    Mary,,mary@yahoo.com
```

count occurencies of emails from 3rd column,file1 in
INPUT2:

```
file2.log
    mary@yahoo.com&fghfgh
    asdda&barry@mail.com
    barry@mail.com&werewr
```

desired
OUTPUT:

```
result.csv
    John,Doe,john@mail.com,0
    Andy,Barry,barry@mail.com,2
    Mary,,mary@yahoo.com,1
```

many thanx!

Comment: Please provide the proper input file in your question.

Comment: Maybe now it's clearer, sorry for problems in question formulation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide valid input, so I used this:

```
John,Doe,barry@mail.com
Andy,Barry,barry@mail.com
Mary,,mary@yahoo.com
```

For which the following awk one-liner gives expected results:

```
awk -F, '{l[NR]=$0;f[NR]=$3;c[$3]++}END{for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print l[i] "," c[f[i]]}'
```

The issue here is that your task requires either two passes.  (f[] is just a convenience to avoid keeping the entire content parsed, or re-parsing it at the end.)  But since I don't understand why you ruled out python or perl (they *are* basic shell tools), perhaps you don't consider awk fair game either...

Comment: Hi, thanx for Your answer. Please, recheck the question, I've edited. I need to input 1 csv file and compare vs another file/s and count occurencies in a second file, not in the first. Awk is ok.